# Forward an incoming OUTLOOK exchangelib message

Tags: exchangelib

I need to forward a new incoming message there may be attachments to another address. But the letter doesn't go away. how do I do this?

```
s = a.inbox.unread_count# количество непрочитанных
if s > 0:
    print(s, '  Получено новых писем')
    for item in my_folder.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:s]:
        print(item.subject, # тема письма
              #item.body, # текст письма
              #item.attachments,
              item.last_modified_name, # от кого
              item.display_cc, # в копии
              item.text_body, # текст в txt
              item.message_id,
              )
        #ПОМЕЧАЕМ ПИСЬМО КАК ПРОЧИТАННОЕ
        item.is_read = True
        item.save()
        #пересылаем письмо
        m = a.sent.get(subject=item.subject)
        m.reply(subject='Re: Daily motivation', body='ответ на сообщение',
                to_recipients=['eagl69@mail.ru'])
        m.send(id=item.message_id)
        # сохраняем вложения
        for attachment in item.attachments:
            with open(attachment.name, 'wb') as f:
                try:
                    f.write(attachment.content)
                except:
                    print('Файл не записан, или отсутствует')
else:
    print('Нет новых писем')
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand exactly what you want to happen, and what you are seeing instead. Can you elaborate? Also, try cleaning up your code example so it contains only the essential parts showing your issue.

Comment: But maybe you are looking for the `.forward()` method? `m.forward(subject='Fwd: Daily motivation', body='Hey, look at this!', to_recipients=['carl@example.com', 'denice@example.com'])`